# Open PDF File or Web Address with PDF File in IOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I'm tossing together an app for my company and looking to open a pdf file when a cell in a table view is selected, or to have it open the web address where the pdf is located. I have the table view built and am just looking to finish this portion of the app to complete it. Any ideas would be great.

```
@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *currentarry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MARCH 2014", nil];
    NSDictionary *currentInDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:currentIssueArray forKey:@"Issues"];


    NSArray *previousIssueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"JANUARY 2014 ", nil];
    NSDictionary *PreviousinDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:previousIssueArray forKey:@"Issues"];

    [listOfItems addObject:Current];
    [listOfItems addObject:Previous];

    //Initialize the copy array.
    copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Set the title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
```

Comment: What exactly do you need? To open a pdf file you need have to use an UIWebView for that.

Comment: I am looking to open a url that contains a pdf from a specific table cell. Each cell will contain its on url. EX. Cell a opens google.com, cell b opens stack overflow.com, etc..

Comment: From where do you grab the URL from so I can adapt the code below for you?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Comment: I have updated the code section above, where with that uiapplication code be placed in the location of the current code.

Comment: Chris Barber, you won't be able to open the URL from the viewDidLoad method if you want the user to choose from a specific cell. You need to do it from the method tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPatth:, like I showed on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `index` of the cell related to the `URL` you'd like to open, using the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, like so (supposing the `URL` string is displayed on the cell, or you can grab it from elsewhere):

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cellText]];

}
```